# Log only if request exceeds a threshold

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I have a spring project with log4j. I have a requirement to write logs only if the request exceeds a certain threshold. Is there a way to configure log4j to only write logs if the request time exceeds a certain threshold (eg 10 seconds)?

Comment: What "reqest time" are you referring to, or more specifically, what request are you refering to?

Comment: an HTTP request (POST, PUT, GET etc).. If its taking longer than n seconds then only then I want to write logs / log

Answer (score 0):

No, it's business logic you had to implement. Log4j is not "coupled" to your http client lib, and if such ability is not on your lib, then program it. Either per operation, via measuring the times, and log on long operations, or some aspect to catch all the operations.

Comment: I figured such- ended up programming an adapter to collect all logs and on close determine if it should commit them.